# Writing $\sqrt[4]{16}$ in polar form and acquiring a solution that doesn't exist

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$$\sqrt[4]{16} = ?$$

$$16 = |16|(\cos(0)+i\sin(\pi))$$
the equality above holds.

$$\sqrt[4]{16} = |\sqrt[4]{16}|(\cos(0 + \frac{2k\pi}{4})+i\sin(\pi+\frac{2k\pi}{4})) $$
using De Moivre"s formula we get:
$$ \sqrt[4]{16} = 2(\cos(0 + \frac{2k\pi}{4})+i\sin(\pi+\frac{2k\pi}{4}))$$
$$\text{for k = 0, we get one of the correct solutions,  but for k = 1 we get $-i\sqrt{2}$ which is not a solution.}$$

Why does this kind of approach not work?

Comment: The agrument of sine in the first expression should be $0$, and not $\pi$...

Comment: @dfnu I know, but why doesn't sine with $\pi$ also work ?

Comment: Then the problem would be your application of de Moivre's formula, which is not correct

Comment: That is evident if you know the exponential expression of the complex number, by the way.

Comment: @dfnu I see, thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to express a complex number in polar coordinates is $z = |z| (\cos(\mathrm{arg \ z}) + i\sin (\mathrm{arg \ z}))$. Crucially, note that both the cosine and sine are of the same angle, the argument of the complex number.

What you did is wrong because you have $0$ as one angle and $\pi$ as the other. You cannot apply De Moivre's to that expression because that is not a proper polar form.

Instead, start with $16 = 16 (\cos 2k\pi + i \sin 2k\pi)$.

Answer (score 1):

Because starting at $\sin (\pi)$ as opposed to $\sin(0)$, you’re basically multiplying the imaginary part with $-1$.

Comment: I do not believe that is true since $\sin(\pi) = 0$

Comment: what do mean, exactly?

Comment: Well, $\sin(0+\varepsilon) = - \sin(\pi+\varepsilon)$

Comment: I understand now, I shifted the other angle... thank you